# Performance optimization for route calculations via mouse drag

Tags: optimization, here-api, drag

Our Team is currently working on a car routing web application with the HERE-API. To meet the users expectations, we want to integrate all the typical features everyone is used to nowadays, most importantly the possibility to manipulate a route interactively by dragging waypoints out of it.

While for the most part everything seems to work fine, we are experiencing serious performance issues on long routes combined with large drag distances.

Our applicaton works a follows:

-at first the user has to provide two addresses

-the route is initially calculated using a full calculateroute request (representation = 'display')

-now, when the user drags the route, we request a new route with a waypoint at the mouse position and reduced response data (representation = 'dragNDrop') every 500ms for the time the dragging process lasts

While this procedure is working really well and fast when zooming in to a small section of the route, it is very slow and laggy when zooming out to country size and dragging while the whole route is being displayed. Implementing a throttling mechanism and experimenting with different call rates helped a bit, but not as much as we hoped.

Having a look at the constant performance on wego.here.com, we were hoping that there might be a better way to implement this feature with the HERE-API or maybe some kind of optimization.

We would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you share the full routing request you make when dragging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply! It had been pretty crazy this year so this post is a bit late - my apologies for that.

The solution to our Problem was a small adjustment to a parameter value. We lowered the value of the parameter 'resolution' to '25:25' for calculateRoute-Requests while doing route draggings.

Answer (score 0):

Routing API will provide the best solution with respect to the use case. can you please share the API response time or full API request. please check clustering document if it aligns with the use case.

> developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/clustering.html

if it does relate to the number of request(which cause the implementation of throttling and increase API requests), please connect us at

> developer.here.com/contact-us